# How to show/hide a search bar inside a navigation bar (iOS 8) as in Apple's Calendar app?

Tags: uibarbuttonitem, searchbar

How to implement: I have UIBarButtonItem with a search icon, after I click on it, I want to show the search bar in navigation bar and on click cancel button in search bar, I want to show navigation bar without search and with buttons and title like in IOS 7 calendar app.

Answer (score 8):

Setup an action for your search button to present a `UISearchController`.  See the `Search` > `Present Over Navigation Bar` demo in Apple's [UICatalog sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html):

```
- (IBAction)searchButtonClicked:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    // Create the search results view controller and use it for the UISearchController.
    AAPLSearchResultsViewController *searchResultsController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:AAPLSearchResultsViewControllerStoryboardIdentifier];

    // Create the search controller and make it perform the results updating.
    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:searchResultsController];
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = searchResultsController;
    self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;

    // Present the view controller.
    [self presentViewController:self.searchController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: The link you shared is very useful.. (+1)