# Make UISearchBar dismiss like Music App

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

Notice how the `searchBar` magnifying glass and placeholder text both shift over on dismissal:

[image]

Is there any way I could dismiss this search bar without the text and icon moving over? See the animation of the Music app for the animation I am trying to achieve.

I have a `UISeachBar` that gets presented when the search button is clicked in a nav bar.

```
@IBAction func searchButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    presentViewController(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Now when the cancel button is pressed, I want the whole view to move up without seeing the SearchBar icon and placeholder text slide to the center of the searchBar as the view moves up off screen.

I know there is the method `searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar:)`, but this seems to automatically dismiss the SearchBar and I don't know how to control that.

How can I make the SearchBar dismiss like the one in the Music app?

**EDIT**: Here is the only delegate method I am using:

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    masterFilter.removeAll()
    filterContentForSearchText(searchController.searchBar.text!)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Can you post any `UISearchBarDelegate` methods you may have added?  if you are calling `resignFirstResponder`, it would trigger the undesired animation.

Comment: You've set your `searchBar.delegate`.  But there is no `searchBarCancelButtonClicked` or other searchBar methods in your code?  The only thing I can account for at this point is something additional in your project that was left over from the previous approach you tried, which is affecting the new approach you switched to.

Comment: Forgive me. I do have `searchBarCancelButtonClicked`, but no code inside of it. I'm not sure what code to put in there to achieve my desired animation.

Comment: None.  You shouldn't include it, or even need to set `searchBar.delegate` since filtering is handled by the searchResultsUpdater. Try removing `searchController.searchBar.delegate = self`, as Apple doesn't even include it in their example.

Comment: Ok, I removed that line. Back to my original problem, how should I achieve this animation?

Comment: I downloaded and compiled `UICatalog` to try to figure out what error you were seeing, and it compiled and ran cleanly with Xcode 6.4.  No errors or crashes.  The sample code is animating fine, so it's got to be something in your code.  Can you share your project and let another set of eyes try to spot what is wrong?  Can you share a video of the broken animation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88274/discussion-between-user3711622-and-petahchristian).

Answer (score 1):

This is how I have achieved this. It is simple and easy.

```
extension UIViewController {


    func setNavigationBarItem() {

        let searchaButton = UIButton.init(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30))
        searchaButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "search.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        searchaButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.searchPressed), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)


        let rightButton: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: searchaButton)

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton

    }


    public func searchPressed(){

        var searchController: UISearchController!

        // Create the search results view controller and use it for the UISearchController.
        let searchResultsController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SearchResultController") as! SearchResultsViewController

        // Create the search controller and make it perform the results updating.
        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultsController)
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = searchResultsController
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false

        // Present the view controller.
        presentViewController(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}
```

**Note:**

This code is for old swift version.

[image]

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The searchBar expands to the right because the search is being cancelled, and the cancel button is disappearing.

Instead of canceling the search and triggering that animation, simply explicitly dismiss the search controller.

You can do this by setting

```
searchController.active = false
```

Comment: Putting this in `searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar:)` has no effect on the animation.

Comment: Because you're still canceling the search since the cancel button was clicked.  Again, I suggest you download and run Apple's [UICatalog sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html).  It does exactly what you are asking, and animates exactly the same way Music does.  Look and see how they dismiss their search controller.  You'll discover that the search is not being cancelled.  I could paste the code but you will understand if you discover how it works on your own.

Comment: I would love to run the UICatalog project, but there are 4 errors in the project. It does not build.

Comment: Are you using Xcode 6 or 7?  It was updated to Swift 1.2 and worked as of Xcode 6.3.

Comment: I am using Xcode 6.4. It doesn't work in Xcode 7 neither.

Comment: Did you try compiling Objective C version?

Comment: I got it to compile and run but it crashes right away with an uncaught exception of type NSException. I am out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

To make this animation work, you'll need to understand custom `UIViewController` [transitions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate_protocol/). Within the `UISearchBarDelegate` method `-searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar:)`, you'll need to do a few things:

1. [Hide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006934-CH3-SW36) the `UINavigationBar` on the [UISearchController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:) [dismissal](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:)
2. Animate the [UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/) to the bottom of the frame and fade out.
3. If you're presenting search modally, ensure that you're setting the [modalPresentationStyle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/modalPresentationStyle) to `UIModalPresentationCurrentContext`.